# Getting an invalid argument in C#

Tags: c#, oledbconnection

```
void Fillcombo()
    {
        OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection("Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=Library.accdb");
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(@"SELECT * FROM Books", cn);
        cmd.Connection = cn;

        OleDbDataReader dr;
        try
        {
            cn.Open();
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                string b = dr.GetString("book");//This is the line where im getting an error
                cboProgramming.Items.Add(b);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("f");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 4):

[OleDbDataReader.GetString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdatareader.getstring(v=vs.110).aspx) takes an `int` as a parameter, and returns the `string` value.

Answer (score 1):

```
    // Summary:
    //     Gets the value of the specified column as a string.
    //
    // Parameters:
    //   ordinal:
    //     The zero-based column ordinal.
    //
    // Returns:
    //     The value of the specified column.
    //
    // Exceptions:
    //   System.InvalidCastException:
    //     The specified cast is not valid.
    public override string GetString(int ordinal);
```

you should pass an int.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want something more like:

```
string b = dr.GetString(dr.GetOrdinal("book"));
```

As the `GetString()` method (like `GetInt32` and all the others) take the column index - which can be returned with the `GetOrdinal` method